# Google Sheets SUM() does not return zero, but an extremely small number instead?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with the following values:

```
 12.4840
 -8.1870
 -0.9630
 -3.3210
  3.4550
  0.3140
  3.3470
 -7.1290
```

If I `SUM()` these, the expected result is `0` (zero). But it is not. The value that Google Sheets returns is actually `0.000000000000000888178419700125`. This is super weird, as none of the values have more than 4 decimals.

I found this out after debugging for hours because some conditional formatting is supposed to color every cell that has a `0` value, but this (and some other) cells just would not change color accordingly.

I have an example here: [Stackoverflow Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VGwVWw2ZFW0qYQjxN6jomZLyxssKp48ykE5jGWIqMFA/edit#gid=0). Can someone please explain me what is going wrong here, and how I can get the `SUM()` to return true zero? I have tried everything (format input as numbers, as text, force to numbers in sum() formula) but nothing seems to work.

[Update] I have added a few more examples in the Sheet.

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me, it would probably be best to report it.

Comment: read about floating point representation... floating points can lead to unexpected results sometimes, but this is not a bug - instead its a result of how floating points are represented internally.

Comment: But how do I fix this? Like, I have conditional formatting in the rest of my sheet that colors cells based on whether the value is `0` or not, and this now obviously messes up.

Answer (score 3):

actually, this is not a bug and it is pretty common. its called floating point "error" and in a nutshell, it has to do things with how decimal numbers are stored within a google sheets (even [excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113) or any other app)

more details can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

to counter it you will need to introduce rounding like:

```
=ROUND(SUM(A1:A))
```

this is not an ideal solution for all cases so depending on your requirements you may need to use these instead of `ROUND`:

```
ROUNDUP
ROUNDDOWN
TRUNC
TEXT
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I fix it in my sheet? I have many other formulas and conditional formatting checking for `0` (zero) values and I have many instances where this is now going wrong bc of this issue. I have added another few examples to my shared Sheet, one of which actually is going well (with as many decimals).

Comment: @Pr0no see your sheet. left you there some solutions