# Difference in value of two same time google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, time, floating-point, rounding, number-formatting

Why the values of two identical times are different from each other, unable to use vlookup due to this

Note: Times are taken from two different sources, one is generated as CSV from a website and the other was manually entered.

Example:

Time    Values
10:00 AM    0.416666666666666
10:00 AM    0.416666666666667
FALSE

How to Solve this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens due to a "rounding error" more on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72230592/5632629

in your case, you just need to trim/round it 12-digit decimal:

[image]