# Google Sheets Less than or equal (<=) provide wrong result

Tags: google-sheets, floating-point, google-sheets-formula, rounding, precision

Formula `0<=(1.36*100/1.36)-100` returns FALSE while expects TRUE.

But

`0<=(1.26*100/1.26)-100` returns correct result TRUE.
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you run:

```
=(1.36*100/1.36)-100
```

and expand decimal places you will get:

[image]

which is totally fine even if you do not expect such behavior. this is due to how google sheets stores the numbers and this "nonsense" is called "rounding error" (yet it is not an error)

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72230592/5632629

in your case try:

```
=0<=ROUND((1.36*100/1.36)-100)
```

[image]